# Are there any parametric assumptions for Linear Mixed Models - lmer (multivariate model)

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, model, computer-vision

Are there any parametric assumptions for Linear Mixed Models - lmer (multivariate model)? I saw a few videos or journals that have reported results without resulting in any assumptions? any answer with reference will be appreciated

Answer (score 8):

The fact that they didn't mention assumptions doesn't mean there aren't any.  Many strong assumptions are made, e.g.,

- The right hand side of the model is structurally correct with regard to nonlinearities and interactions
- The overall error term is normal with constant variance
- The random effects are normal with constant variance
- The within-subject correlation is constant.  If analyzing longitudinal data this is unlikely to be true, as typically correlations are stronger for measurements taken closer together in time.